# If $A \in B$, then $A \subseteq B$ (verify proof)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's a trivial exercise but I'm not sure my steps are correct, and also I would like to know if there's a quicker way to prove.

By the definition of a subset: $A \subseteq \cup B \leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \to x \in \cup B)$

If $A = \emptyset$ then it follows vacuously, since $\forall x (x \notin \emptyset)$.

If not, then take any $x \in A$ and the definition of Union $x \in \cup B \leftrightarrow \exists C (x \in C \wedge C \in B)$ and we have $x \in \cup B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge A \in B)$

This means that $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in \cup B)$ which is precisely the definition of $A \subseteq \cup B$

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a typo in the title?

Comment: Because you do not have the statement you are trying to prove in the body of the post, and your title is plainly wrong, it is difficult to say what it is you think you are trying to do, and therefore impossible to tell if you are doing it correctly. (1) The subject line is not part of the post, anymore than the envelope is part of the letter inside inside it. Please include all relevant information *in the body of the post*. (2) Please double check before posting. (3) Please state clearly what you are trying to prove.

Comment: You appear to have a union in $\cup B$.  What is being unioned?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know $\cup B$ as a shorthand for $$\bigcup_{C\in B}C$$That looks to be what the OP is after too.

Comment: @Arthur I agree with that interpretation.  I hope that the OP clarifies the notation that $B$ is indeed an index set.

Comment: I'm very sorry, there's a typo in the title. The correct form is A∈B → A⊆∪B

Comment: Also, B is an index set, as @Arthur pointed out

Comment: Then edit your title to remove the typo, and include the information in the post.